# How to prevent copying of functions, creating constructor function that invokes array of functions

Tags: javascript

Currently, I have defined a constructor that will make an object with a private variable, funcs.

The extend method will add new functions onto the funcs array.

The resolve function will invoke all functions in the funcs array:

```
var extendableFunc = function() {

   var funcs = [];

   this.resolve = function () {
      for(var i=0; i<funcs.length; i+=1) {
         funcs[i]();

      }
   };

   this.extend = function(newFn) {
      funcs.push(newFn);
   }

};


var exampleExt = new extendableFunc();

exampleExt.extend(function() {

   alert("hello!");
});

exampleExt.resolve();
```

To add the same function into the funcs array of multiple extendableFunc objects, I can write a function like so:

```
var extendMultiple = function(exts, func) {
   for(var i=0; i<exts.length; i+=1) {
      exts[i].extend(func);
   } 
}
```

However, I believe that this will create a new copy of the function that I am adding to each funcs array.

If I am adding a function to the invocation array, I want there to be only one function— and there are just references to it in the arrays.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: "However, I believe that this will create a new copy of the function that I am adding" Have you actually tried it to see whether it is making copies or not? Edit: I'm certain that this does not create copies. I have tested this myself.

Comment: Yes I apologize, I do not know exactly how to test if it does. How did you test?

Comment: I added a function which retrieved the `funcs` variable, ran your functions, and then checked to make sure the two functions were indeed the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functions are a type of javascript object and are passed or assigned by reference - putting a function reference into an array does not make a copy of the function.

Comment: That's what I thought initially, however I noticed that when you assign a variable b=a when a is a function, and you later assign a to (for instance) a string, b is still the function that "a" was once assigned to. I thought therefore created a copy :/ I suppose it just changes what "a" references to

Comment: @TaylorMac - your second notion is what happens.

Comment: Very good. Thank you, I learn so much from smart people like you and Xymostech